# Why is the alignment of an MdFramed environment affected by an included caption differently in the scrbook and the article document classes?

Tags: mdframed, alignment, scrbook

I am trying to produce a floating table with a caption, both the table and the caption should be surrounded by a frame. The frame should have a width which reflects the size of the table and the caption, not the entire line width, and I want everything centered. The following MWE shows the expected and desired behavior for the article document class:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}

\NewEnviron{MyMdframed}[1][]{%
    \setlength{\MyMdframedWidthTweak}{\dimexpr%
        +\mdflength{innerleftmargin}
        +\mdflength{innerrightmargin}
        +\mdflength{leftmargin}
        +\mdflength{rightmargin}
    }%
    \savebox0{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax}%
            \BODY
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    \begin{mdframed}[
        userdefinedwidth=\dimexpr\wd0+\MyMdframedWidthTweak\relax, 
        #1]
        \usebox0
    \end{mdframed}
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]  

\begin{table}[h!]
     \begin{MyMdframed}[align=center]
         \caption{This is my caption text}
         \begin{tabular}{l|ccc}\hline
              Szenario $s$      &   1       &   2       &   3   \\ \hline
              Premium           &   3000    &   3500    &   4500 \\
              DeLuxe            &   1200    &   1500    &   2500 \\ \hline
          \end{tabular}     
      \end{MyMdframed}
 \end{table}

 \lipsum[1] 

 \end{document}
```

Using the *article* document class, everything looks as expected:

[image]

However, if instead I use the *scrbook* class, the table is no longer centered and the width of the box now equals the line width:
[image]

What do I need to do to see the same nice adjusted width and centered alignment of my table of the *article* class when using the *scrbook* class instead?

Thanks a lot!

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution uwing `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}  


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{mytable}[2][]{float=htb,
                                               sharp corners,
                                               boxrule=0.5pt,
                                               titlerule = 0pt,  
                                               colback=white,
                                               colframe=black,
                                               colbacktitle=white, 
                                               coltitle=black,
                                               halign=center, 
                                               capture=hbox,  
                                               title={#2}, 
                                               every float=\centering, 
                                               #1}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]  

\begin{mytable}[label=myref]{This is my caption text}
         \begin{tabular}{l|ccc}\hline
              Szenario $s$      &   1       &   2       &   3   \\ \hline
              Premium           &   3000    &   3500    &   4500 \\
              DeLuxe            &   1200    &   1500    &   2500 \\ \hline
          \end{tabular}     
\end{mytable}
 \lipsum[1] 

 \end{document}
```